# Python не видит импортированный класс

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame
from constants import *
from Player import *
from Block import *

pygame.init()

class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = (WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size)
        pygame.display.set_caption("window")

        self.blank_space = pygame.image.load("data/blank_space.png")
        self.brick = pygame.image.load("data/brick_2.png")
        self.player_sprite = pygame.image.load("data/Player_2.png")
        self.running = True

        self.Player = Player()

        self.background=[]

        for y in range(WINDOW_WIDTH//BLOCK_SIZE+1):             
            self.background.append([])
            for x in range(WINDOW_HEIGHT//BLOCK_SIZE+1):
                self.background[y].append(self.brick)
        for row in range(1,WINDOW_WIDTH//BLOCK_SIZE-1):        
            for column in range(1,WINDOW_HEIGHT//BLOCK_SIZE-1):
                self.background[row][column]=self.blank_space


        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.main_loop()

    def draw_back(self, background):
        start_pos = [0,0]
        for row in background:
            for column in row:
                self.screen.blit(column,start_pos)
                start_pos[1]+=BLOCK_SIZE
            start_pos[0]+=BLOCK_SIZE
            start_pos[1]=0

    def main_loop(self):
        while self.running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.running = False

            self.keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  
            if self.keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                self.Player.x_pos += self.Player.x_speed
            if self.keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                self.Player.x_pos -= self.Player.x_speed
            if self.keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                self.Player.y_pos -= self.Player.y_speed
            if self.keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                self.Player.y_pos += self.Player.y_speed

            self.draw_back(self.background)

            self.Player.draw_player(self.player_sprite)

            self.clock.tick(60)

            pygame.display.flip()

        pygame.quit()

Main = Main()
```

Решил написать что-то на подобии игры на python используя библиотеку PyGame
,но столкнулся с проблемой что сейчас при запуске выскакивает ошибка

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
>     from Player import *
>   File "C:\Users\gorko\Desktop\Python\my_game\Player.py", line 3, in 
> <module>
>     from Main import *
>   File "C:\Users\gorko\Desktop\Python\my_game\Main.py", line 77, in <module>
>     Main = Main()
>   File "C:\Users\gorko\Desktop\Python\my_game\Main.py", line 21, in __init__
>     self.Player = Player()
> NameError: name 'Player' is not defined
> ```

Ниже код класса Player

```
import pygame
from constants import *
from Main import *

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x_speed = 5
        self.y_speed = 5
        self.x_pos = 50
        self.y_pos = 50


    def draw_player(self,player_sprite):
        Main.screen.blit(player_sprite,(self.x_pos,self.y_pos))
```

Comment: У вас циклические импорты — Player импортирует Main, который импортирует Player, который импортирует Main, который импортирует Player, который импортирует Main, который... Так нельзя делать

Comment: Исправил, заработало